# Select property by string name using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a pretty simple piece of code:

```
var list = new List<MyType>();
list = MyItems.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(e.Text.ToLower())).ToList();
for (int i = itemOffset; i < endOffset; i++)
{
    combo.Items.Add(new ComboItem(list[i].Name, list[i].Id.ToString()));
}
```

What I want to do is to make this a generic function that accepts list of any type and accepts two strings as properties. (In this case two properties that we are looking at are Name and Id.

```
private void MakeCombo<T>(Combo combo, IEnumerable<T> lst, string Field1, string Field2)
{
    var list = list = lst.Where(x => x.Field1.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())).ToList(); //How make this to work???

    for (int i = itemOffset; i < endOffset; i++)
    {
        combo.Items.Add(new ComboItem(list[i].Field1, list[i].Field2.ToString())); //How make this to work???
    }
}
```

Now, I do not understand how can I access properties of generic list by string names (Field1 and Field2).

Comment: What is not working exactly? Any error? Any useful dump?

Comment: You're evaluating searchText.ToLower() for every item in the list. You should store to a local variable so you only have to evaluate it once.

Comment: As a rule, you should avoid doing stuff like this whenever possible (and it's possible here).  Reflection should always be a last resort, just like any other means of treating strings as code.  It's highly fragile, inhibits learning more proper coding methods (you can start to use it as a crutch), creates security vulnerabilities, and is harder to read/understand/maintain over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of solving this problem, if you don't have the ability of creating an interface and ensuring all of the items in the sequence implement that interface (as shown in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349713/1159478)), is to use delegates.  By passing in two functions, each of which take a `T` as input, and return a `string` or `object` as the output, you can mimic that functionality:

```
private void MakeCombo<T>(Combo combo, IEnumerable<T> sequence
    , Func<T, string> field1Selector, Func<T, object> field2Selector)
{
    var foundItems = sequence.Where(item => field1Selector(item).ToLower()
        .Contains(searchText.ToLower()));

    foreach(var item in foundItems)
    {
        combo.Items.Add(new ComboItem(field1Selector(item), field2Selector(item).ToString()));
    }
}
```

From the calling side it might look something like this (to use your first code snippet as an example:

```
MakeCombo(combo, list, item => item.Name, item => item.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing this answer. This is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use reflection:

```
typeof(x).GetField("Field1", BindingFlags.Public).GetValue()
```

You could do that for both objects and compare the values.

Comment: Get value expects one parameter at least. What should it be?

Comment: Whoops, you should pass the instance of the type you want the value of. In this case, x. You should really read about reflection if you want to go down this route. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you could define an interface, describing all the fields available, and make each type, that is suitable for this method implement that interface, it would look like this (and would be IMO better, than accessing fields by names):

```
public interface IFields
{
    string Prop1 { get; set; }
    string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public static void DoSmth<T>(List<T> items) where T : IFields
{
    foreach (T t in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Prop1);
        Console.WriteLine(t.Prop2);
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks awesome. Unfortunately, I cannot describe an interface, because I have no real control over T. Is there any way to do it without an interface?

Comment: @user194076 just use answer by Chris then

Comment: @user194076 Yes, there is.  Just pass in two delegates, such as `Func<T, string>`.  This will be a selector for the text and the value.  When calling the method you can use a lambda, such as `item=>item.Name`.  This has the advantage of 100% compile time safety, unlike the reflection model, as you don't need to worry about whether there is a field with a given name, what it's visibility is, etc, you can just use the function.

Comment: @Servy you probably meant to use the code similar to the one from this question: [what's the advantage of Property Info?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132725/whats-the-advantage-of-property-info) ?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov Nope, there's no need for expressions here.  This is simpler than that.  I guess I'll just write it up as an answer.

Comment: I've added an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14351923/1159478) to explain my comment in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void MakeCombo<T>(Combo combo, IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    List<T> comboList = list.Where(x => ((String)type.GetField("Field1", (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)).GetValue(x)).ToLower().Contains(m_SearchText.ToLower()));

    for (Int32 i = m_ItemOffset; i < m_OffsetEnd; ++i)
        combo.Items.Add(new ComboItem((String)type.GetField("Field1", (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)).GetValue(list[i]), (String)type.GetField("Field2", (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)).GetValue(list[i])));
}
```

Comment: It complains that: The type or namespace name 'x' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) inside a typeof

Comment: The same with typeof(list[i])

Comment: ok it compiles now. The problem I experience though: type.GetField("Name", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance) - this returns null. While this: type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance) returns = {System.Reflection.FieldInfo[2]}
    [0]: {Int32 <Id>k__BackingField}
    [1]: {System.String <Name>k__BackingField} Do you why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show me the code snippets of those fields declarations?

Comment: Like this:  ` [Serializable()]
        public class MyClass
        {
          
            public MyClass()
            {
                ....
            }
            [Serializable()]
            public class MyNestedClass
            {
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }

                public MyNestedClass() { }
                public MyNestedClass(int val0, string val1)
                {
                    Id = val0;
                    Name = val1;
                }
            }`

Comment: Just use BindingFlags.Public. Try,

Comment: Ah damn... you are trying to get Properties, not Fields... you should get the underlying member instead... m_Name and m_Id. Or change type.GetField into Type.GetProperty.

Comment: And you have an Int32 and a String... not two Strings... review your code man or it will be a total disaster :D